# Outputting text to C++ Winform

Tags: c++, winforms

I have a winform which I made in Visual C++ and I've got some code:

```
std::string myString = "My String";
TCHAR myString = _T(myString);
```

Then I try to output it to the Winform with:

```
TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, myString, _tcslen(myString));
```

My errors are with the _T which say:
"LmyString" is undefined

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Comment: ' "LmyString" is undefined' Is the error I get then I hover over the red line

Comment: The _T() macro only works on string literals, not variables.  It was relevant in the previous century, today you say std::wstring myString(L"My String");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mystring` is an `std::string`. Make it an `std::wstring`:

```
std::wstring my_str = L"My String";
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work; I get the same error message as before

Comment: @user2836518 You can't do `Lmystring`. That is parsed as a full variable name. What you want to do is change `myString` from `std::string` to `std::wstring`.

Comment: TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, my_str, _tcslen(my_str)); 
Doesn't let me call my_str
error C2664: 'wcslen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 
My Error:
'std::wstring' to 'const wchar_t *'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: Do `_tcslen(my_str.c_str())`